# New Fireplace Mantel Shelf

Tags: fireplace

So My W̶i̶f̶e̶ Goddess has not liked the fireplace mantel shelf for a long time so she started to do a little demo and what she found did not make her happy. The mantel it-self is only attached to the wall with one nail(on the left side) and the back and one side of mantel had 1/2" molding going around it to keep it from falling. Thank God I never leaned on it nor did she place anything on it that was to heavy. We looked at getting a already made one but because the fireplace is an odd shape, nothing was long enough or wide enough. The measurements on the pic are just the piece of wood and there is a 1/4" gap to the wall. After we come up with the design that we like and start to build, is there anything that we need to be aware of to make it safe.

[image]

Comment: Those brackets should also be providing some support.

Comment: @Ecnerwal you would think that but they are about 1/4" off the brick.